# Google maps autocomplete, fix to the input

Tags: css, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, autocomplete

I'm trying to add a google maps autocomplete input to my ionic app. It works pretty well except when I scroll. As shown on the image:

[image: Position bug when scroll]

So I tried different things like changing the position of *.pac-container* but it doesn't solve the problem.
When I inspect the page, it seems that the results container loads at the end of the page, so it's not easy to make the block stick to the input bar.

I already searched everywhere and didn't fidn any suitable solution ? Does someone have an idea how to do it ?
(It's actually just a simple code like this:

```js
function initialize() {
    var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}, types: ['geocode']}
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), 
        options
    );
}
        
initialize();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GVdK6/265/)

Thanks

Comment: I could not reproduce on your fiddle the autocomplete box looks fine on scrolling, which browser did you experience this issue?

Comment: Hi, here is an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/GVdK6/268/ I got the issue on every browser (so on my Android too).

Comment: Hi, any idea please ? :)

Comment: @RobinFrcd I see you've upvoted an answer, do you mind updating your answer with more specific examples? Been struggling with this for a long time..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same problem. My solution was:

```
$('#inputContainer').scroll(function(){
    //Set new top to autocomplete dropdown
    newTop = $('#autocompleteInput').offset().top + $('#autocompleteInput').outerHeight();
    $('.pac-container').css('top', newTop + 'px');
});
```

This update the dropdown position when container scrolls.

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered the same problem when I was implementing the Autocomplete on a form inside a scrollable modal. If you only have one Autocomplete object then the solution is relatively easy.

1. First make sure that your element's parent has a relative position.
2. Then you need to select the .pac-container and append it to the parent.

   ```
   $("#autocomplete").parent()
       .css({position: "relative"})
       .append(".pac-container");
   ```
3. Finally set the .pac-container left and top position to be below your element. This needs to be done in a stylesheet with the **!important** declaration to ensure it **[overrides](https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/)** the inline styles set by Google's code.

   ```
   // these values will need to be calculated based on your layout
   .pac-container {
       top: 40px !important;
       left: 0px !important;
   }
   ```

This obviously wont work if you have multiple Autocomplete objects on a single page. Luckily I figured out a way to handle that scenario and recently published it in a **[jQuery plugin](http://projects.trentmentink.com/jquery_geocomplete/)** designed to make autocompleting address forms a breeze.

Comment: I like this option the best. I'd probably calculate the new position dynamically though. Also consider putting the `pac-container` above the input when there isn't enough space below.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution check [the example](https://codepen.io/gmkhussain/pen/qPpryg) no issue with position bug when scroll

```
function initAutocomplete() {
      //....codes...
       //....add this code just before close function...
    setTimeout(function(){ 
                $(".pac-container").prependTo("#mapMoveHere");
            }, 300);
}
```

https://codepen.io/gmkhussain/pen/qPpryg

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to set the css as `html,body{overflow-x:visible;}` to make the pac-container fixed to the input field.

Comment: This is no solution.
When you scroll down/up,  you will get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was now able to reproduce the problem, the solution is simply adding `position: relative` to your wrapper `box` and `position: absolute` to your `#autocomplete` input.

I got the solution checking [the example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) provided by the Google team.

I've updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/GVdK6/271/) to match the solution, but it goes like this:

Your updated CSS:

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 200vh;
}

#autocomplete {
    width:350px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but the issue comes when I add a scroll to the div for exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/GVdK6/272/

Comment: It seems that's because the div result pops at the end of the HTML, it's not related to the input.
I've tried some DOM modifications but I don't think it the solution. :/

Answer (score 0):

Since my input field is inside "ion-content", I implemented [Nicolas Pennesi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3089590/nicol%C3%A1s-pennesi)
's answer with ion-content's method:

```
onScroll($event) {
// his code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had so many components nested in the Angular app and tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked. What worked for me is in the main ***styles.sccs*** I added this:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

or you could add to inline CSS in ***index.html***:
[image]