# Getting Latitude and Longitude from Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Im using the Google Places Autocomplete API, to have an input in which users type a city and get suggestions for which place they are searching for.

I need to get **not only** the name of the place but the **Latitude and Longitud** of the place for then centering a google map there.

The problem is that Google Places Autocomplete API just returns **description** of the place but **not the coordinates**, at least with what i tried.

Anybody knows if there is a way to get the Latitud & Longitud in the **same** request?

Many **thanks** to any help :')

Comment: In the same request no, you can get place_id from autocomplete request and use it in place details request to get coordinates.

Comment: That makes me sad you know... thanks for the comment @xomena!

Answer (score 1):

All the information you are looking for can be found inside the [Place Result](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult). This is what your code would look like:

```js
var input        = document.getElementById("address");
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {types: ["geocode"]});

autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", function() {
    var placeResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var name        = placeResult.name;

    // The selected place's position
    var location    = placeResult.geometry.location;

    // The preferred viewport when displaying this Place on a map. 
    // This property will be null if the preferred viewport for the Place is not known.
    var viewport    = placeResult.geometry.viewport;

    // This is assuming your google map is saved in a variable called myMap
    if (viewport) {
       myMap.fitBounds(viewport)
    }
    else if (location) {
       myMap.setCenter(location)
    }
});
```

I recently created a [jQuery plugin](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) that makes interacting with Google Maps Autocomplete a breeze. This would be the code to center a map every time a place was selected:

```js
$("#address").geocomplete({
    map: myMap
});
```

The plugin will also allow you to autofill an address form, adds custom styling, provides callbacks and fixes an annoying [scrolling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143131/google-maps-autocomplete-fix-to-the-input).