# Google maps api autocomplete show only street and street number

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

Now in my input I prints street, street number, state, country..
How can I print only street and street number? 
My code:

```
var options = {
            types: ['geocode']
        };
        var input = document.getElementById('address');
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: So how you _prints street, street number, state, country_ can I know

Comment: The google.maps.places.Autocomplete class will not allow this, you cannot change its formatting. If you need a custom formatting you should implement your own autocomplete based on the google.maps.places.AutocompleteService class. Take a look at documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by overwriting the input's value once a place was selected.

```
var input        = document.getElementById("address");
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {types: ["geocode"]});

autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", function() {
    var placeResult       = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var addressComponents = placeResult.address_components;
    var street            = "";
    var number            = "";

    // loop through addressComponents and find the route and street_number types
    for (var i = 0, i_len = addressComponents.length; i < i_len; i++) {
        var addressType = addressComponents[i].types[0];

        switch(addressType) {
            case "route":
                street = addressComponents[i]["long_name"];
                break;

            case "street_number":
                number = addressComponents[i]["long_name"];
                break;
        }
    }

    input.value = number + " " + street;
});
```

I recently created a [jQuery plugin](http://projects.trentmentink.com/jquery_geocomplete/) that will easily allow you to do this. This would be your new code:

```
$("#address").geocomplete({
  fields: {
    "#address" : "street address"
  }
});
```

The plugin will allow you to autofill any number of fields based on the results of the selected place. It also adds custom styling, provides callbacks and fixes an annoying [scrolling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143131/google-maps-autocomplete-fix-to-the-input).