# Google maps autocomplete style

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, autocomplete

I use in `autocomplete of google-maps` (without a map) on input.

I need that the list of results will open up and not down like the deafult. So I try to change the style of `pac-container` and I see that when I change the top or the margin-top the list is open up.

[image]

My problem is that I want to change the bottom and not the top, because each different amount of results needs a different top but the bottom can remain constant so it is more correct to change it.

I tried it on div that I created and it works great for any amount of results. Always the list (the div) appears above the input.

But the `pac-container` is problematic. Its top probably calculated independently and if I do not change it the bottom does not help.

[image]

I can calculate the desired top every time or delete it completely in any keydown [I tried and it works] but it just causes delay on the screen, and if I type really fast it is not always enough to get the change.

Is there a way to cancel the affect of top, or another way to cause the pac-container to appear above the input for any amount of results?

Comment: can you show your relevant code please

Comment: @לבנימלכה, what matters to this question is the CSS I presented in the question. Let me know if need anything specific.

Comment: to help you we must see an example of you code(css,html) you can post in fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: also see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143131/google-maps-autocomplete-fix-to-the-input

Comment: get us a fiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts over time I found the answer:

Change the top to : `top: auto !important`